# functional component to receive array from parent component and map through it

Tags: javascript, reactjs, oop, ecmascript-6

**UPDATE:** Using the code from u/kinduser this is where I'm at

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MultiChoiceQuestions from '../questions/MultiChoice'
import Question from '../questions/Question'

class CNA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      newChoiceArray: [
        { id: 1, text: '1', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '1' },
        { id: 2, text: '2', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '2' },
        { id: 3, text: '3', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '3' },
        { id: 4, text: 'This is a new question', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '4' },
      ],
      ChoiceArray: [
        { id: 1, text: '1', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '1' },
        { id: 4, text: 'This is a new question', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '4' },
      ],
    }
  }

  handleSelected = selected => {
    console.log('Button Selected', selected)
  }

  render() {
    const { newChoiceArray, ChoiceArray } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <p>This is the cna survey</p>
        <Question questionText="Hello" />
        <MultiChoiceQuestions handleClick={this.handleSelected} multiChoiceArray={newChoiceArray} />
        <MultiChoiceQuestions handleClick={this.handleSelected} multiChoiceArray={ChoiceArray} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CNA
```

Child Component

```
const MultiChoiceQuestions = ({ handleClick, multiChoiceArray }) => {
  const handleClickFn = questionChoice => handleClick(questionChoice)
  {
    console.log('test', multiChoiceArray)
  }
  return (
    <div>
      {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => (
        <MultiChoiceQuestions
          key={questionChoice.id}
          onClick={handleClickFn(questionChoice)}
          choice={questionChoice.text}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

Console output: `test (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]0: {id: 1, text: "1", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "1"}1: {id: 2, text: "2", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "2"}2: {id: 3, text: "3", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "3"}3: {id: 4, text: "This is a new question", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "4"}length: 4__proto__: Array(0)
CNA.js:23 Button Selected {id: 1, text: "1", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "1"}
CNA.js:23 Button Selected {id: 2, text: "2", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "2"}
CNA.js:23 Button Selected {id: 3, text: "3", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "3"}
CNA.js:23 Button Selected {id: 4, text: "This is a new question", questionId: "favourite number?", value: "4"}
MultiChoice.js:23 test undefined
MultiChoice.js:23 test undefined`
```

So it looks like the array's from parent component is defined, for some reason selecting the buttons and then the array becomes undefined

Is this possible? My parent component has an array of objects, my child component renders buttons based on the number of objects inside of that array.

So basically I don't want my parent component to map and render the buttons, I want to pass my array as props, and then the child component will render the buttons (n=objects in array)

[Sandbox Link](https://codesandbox.io/s/create-react-app-hqh62)

pseudo  child component would look something like this

```
 <MultiChoiceQuestion
            key={questionChoice.id}
            handleClick={() => this.handleSelected(questionChoice)}
            onClick={this.handleSelected}
            questions={multiChoiceArray} // will receive array as props
            choice={questionChoice.text}
  />
```

This is how everything is structured at the momemnt

```
const MultiChoiceQuestion = props => {
  const { handleClick, choice } = props
  return (
    <div>
     // I want my array.map to live somwhere in this component
      <button onClick={handleClick} type="button">
        {choice}
      </button>
    </div>
  )
```

Parent component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import MultiChoiceQuestion from '../questions/MultiChoice'
import Question from '../questions/Question'

class CNA extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      multiChoiceArray: [
        { id: 1, text: '1', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '1' },
        { id: 2, text: '2', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '2' },
        { id: 3, text: '3', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '3' },
        { id: 4, text: 'This is a new question', questionId: 'favourite number?', value: '4' },
      ],
    }
    this.handleSelected = this.handleSelected.bind(this)
  }

  handleSelected = selected => {
    console.log('Button Selected', selected)
  }

  render() {
    const { multiChoiceArray } = this.state
    return (
      <div>
        <p>This is the cna survey</p>
        <Question questionText="Hello" />
        {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => ( // Don't want this map function here
          <MultiChoiceQuestion
            key={questionChoice.id}
            handleClick={() => this.handleSelected(questionChoice)}
            onClick={this.handleSelected}
            choice={questionChoice.text}
          />
        ))}
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default CNA
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course it's possible - just move the `map` logic into your child component.

```
const MultiChoiceQuestions = ({ handleClick, multiChoiceArray }) => {
  const handleClickFn = (questionChoice) => handleClick(questionChoice);

  return (
    <div>
       {multiChoiceArray.map(questionChoice => (
         <MultiChoiceQuestion
           key={questionChoice.id}
           handleClick={handleClickFn(questionChoice)}
           onClick={this.handleSelected}
           choice={questionChoice.text}
         />
       ))}
    </div>
);
```

And inside your parent:

```
<MultiChoiceQuestions 
    handleClick={this.handleSelected} 
    multiChoiceArray={this.state.multiChoiceArray} />
```

Comment: Component name should be MultiChoiceQuestions : )

Comment: Hmm, I don't think this is quite what I'm after, If I have multiple MultiChoiceQuestion components in my parent component, I want to be able to feed in different arrays. the array param would be a prop

Comment: @invrt Well, using such solution you are actually able to feed different arrays

Comment: I must be doing something wrong then, I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" is undefined on multiChoice component.  Is it possible to have a bit more of an explanation for your answer please?

Comment: @invrt Updated answer:)

Comment: @kinduser Ah, I can see where I went wrong, thanks for that! Though there's one more thing, it says "handle click" has already been declared on line " const handleClick = (questionChoice) => handleClick(questionChoice);" Sorry for being annoying

Comment: @invrt Oh, my bad. Used the same name twice. Fixed

Comment: @kinduser Updated post with sandbox: Ok, so i tried to make a sandbox for easier debugging, but they seem to be having issues with the new version of react. Anyway...I'm getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSelected' of undefined" on my parent :\

Comment: @kinduser, Not really, there's some bug that doesn't necessarily have anything to do with my code, but I put it up there anyway. Was trying to make things easier for you. Right now the error is :"TypeError: Cannot read property 'handleSelected' of undefined" on parent component

Comment: @invrt You dont have to bind it, because `handleSelected` is an arrow function. Also you could just try `handleSelected() { ... }` and keep the binding

Comment: TypeError: handleClick is not a function on line   const handleClickFn = questionChoice => handleClick(questionChoice)

Comment: @kinduser Looks like I had a typo in my code, but now I am getting, TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined in the functional Component